# The privacy of different sexes in Islam Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

On this site I have seen many question discussing private matter of men so openly

E.g.: [Should some one make ghusul after inserting an apparatus into the anus?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13322/does-inserting-an-apparatus-into-anus-break-ghusl)

Which I don't think is right.

We must respect our Muslim sister that are coming to this site and they also know and share their knowledge about Islam and it not about just our sisters it's also about privacy.

Comment: why this question get negative mark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Islamic tradition has always discussed matters related to sexuality openly and respectfully, going right back to the Prophet (saws) himself. As long as things are kept respectful and not vulgar, I don't see why we should do things any differently. Give your fellow Muslims, including the sisters, some credit. We are all adults capable of reading these questions and answers.